# Ordering of array values to match another array ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is use the order of one array to follow the order of another...

For example... **(Using ES6 React)**

```
const orderArr = ["Daniel","Lucas","Gwen","Henry","Jasper"];
const nameArr = ["Gwen","Jasper","Daniel"];
```

to return

```
Daniel // first
Gwen   // second
Jasper // third
```

so the new array would look like `const newNameArr = ["Daniel","Gwen","Jasper"];` // following the order

`orderArr` is the ordered array I'd like to follow. So if any other arrays come about (`nameArr`) they should follow the order of `orderArr`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the ones that don't appear in both arrays, using `orderArr` as the base. This ensures they'll appear in the same order as they appear in `orderArr`.

```js
const orderArr = ["Daniel","Lucas","Gwen","Henry","Jasper"];
const nameArr = ["Gwen","Jasper","Daniel"];
const newNameArr = orderArr.filter((x) => nameArr.indexOf(x) > -1);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newNameArr, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Hmm not exactly looking to filter out anything, the values of orders of both arrays will most likely contain any values like "student, commercial, bikeathon, reading".... I'm more concerned about the position of the array orders

Comment: @Modelesq Exactly. This doesn't change the contents of either array. It creates a new array which has the contents of `nameArr` but in the order they appear in `orderArr`.

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately it's throwing an empty array for me. Might be something on my end